# Bot to login into a web system using C# WebBrowser

Tags: c#, html, winforms, webbrowser-control

I'm trying to create a simple bot to login into a web system using C# WebBrowser.

```
        //Get the WebBrowser document
        doc = wbNavegador.Document;
        //Get login and password input
        HTMLInputElement login = (HTMLInputElement)doc.GetElementById("username").DomElement;
        HTMLInputElement password = (HTMLInputElement)doc.GetElementById("password").DomElement;
        //Insert data
        login.innerText = "admin";
        password.innerText = "@ns@l123";
        //Get login button
        var buttons = doc.GetElementsByTagName("Button");
        //Wait 1 second or the login input wont work
        Util.Utilidades.WaitNSeconds(1);
        //Call angular action "login()"
        foreach (HtmlElement button in buttons)
        {
            if (button != null)
            {
                if (button.GetAttribute("ng-click").Equals("login()"))
                {
                    button.InvokeMember("Click");
                }
            }
        }
```

My problem is, when i use login/password.value and i call the login() function i get an error saying the inputs are empty, when i use InnerText the login works but the password value goes to the placeholder.

Using InnerText the error says "Insert the password"

[image: Insert the password]

Using Value the error says "Insert the username"

[image: Insert the username]

Comment: what if you choose `innerText` for login and `value` for password?

Comment: using value on password the error says to insert it, looks like value only insert visually.

Comment: Is that *your* "websystem"? Can you use a Web-API instead of trying to automate a GUI? Most providers of such systems explicitly do not want bots to use it.

Comment: It is not my websystem, it is from a device o bought it has an localhost web system and i want to use the bot  to access it and download the data

Answer (score -1):

I don't know why but I put `password.value = "@ns@l123"; password.innerText = "@ns@l123";` and it worked